# When I run my code I don't get the histograms that I want in Python

Tags: python

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I don't see anything when I run my code. This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readData():
    df = pd.read_excel('BakeryData_Vilnius.xlsx')
    print(df.head())
    return df

def filterData(df):
    filterWeekday = df[df['weekday'].isin(["5", "6", "7"])]
    filterDate = df[(df['date'] < '2021-03-01') & (df['date'] > '2022-03-01')]
    dataFiltered = df.loc[filterWeekday & filterDate]
    return dataFiltered 

def dataMainStreetA(dataFiltered):
    d_MSA_5 = dataFiltered[(dataFiltered['weekday']== 5) & (dataFiltered['main street A'])]
    d_MSA_6 = dataFiltered[(dataFiltered['weekday']== 6) & (dataFiltered['main street A'])]
    d_MSA_7 = dataFiltered[(dataFiltered['weekday']== 7) & (dataFiltered['main street A'])]
    return d_MSA_5, d_MSA_6, d_MSA_7

def dataStationA(dataFiltered):
    d_SA_5 = dataFiltered[(dataFiltered['weekday']== 5) & (dataFiltered['station A'])]
    d_SA_6 = dataFiltered[(dataFiltered['weekday']== 6) & (dataFiltered['station A'])]
    d_SA_7 = dataFiltered[(dataFiltered['weekday']== 7) & (dataFiltered['station A'])]
    return d_SA_5, d_SA_6, d_SA_7

def plotHistograms (d_MSA_5, d_MSA_6, d_MSA_7, d_SA_5, d_SA_6, d_SA_7):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

    plt.subplot(2,3,1) 
    plt.hist(d_MSA_5, bins=15)
    plt.title('Main Street A - Friday')
    plt.xlabel('Demand')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')

    plt.subplot(2,3,2)
    plt.hist(d_MSA_6, bins=15)
    plt.title('Main Street A - Saturday')
    plt.xlabel('Demand')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')

    plt.subplot(2,3,3)
    plt.hist(d_MSA_7, bins=15)
    plt.title('Main Street A - Saturday')
    plt.xlabel('Demand')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')

    plt.subplot(2,3,4)
    plt.hist(d_SA_5, bins=15)
    plt.title('Station A - Friday')
    plt.xlabel('Demand')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')

    plt.subplot(2,3,5)
    plt.hist(d_SA_6, bins=15)
    plt.title('Station A - Saturday')
    plt.xlabel('Demand')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')

    plt.subplot(2,3,6)
    plt.hist(d_SA_7, bins=15)
    plt.title('Station A - Sunday')
    plt.xlabel('Demand')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe none of the functions you have defined are called anywhere.

Comment: The problem in your code is that you have defined a bunch of functions, but you haven't called any of them.

Comment: Please note that `5, 6, and 7` are very different from `"5", "6" and "7"`.  You need to know whether your data are strings or integers.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't CALLED any of your functions.  I suspect you want this at the end:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = readData()
    df = filterData(df)
    m5,m6,m7 = dataMainStreetA(df)
    d5,d6,d7 = dataStationA(df)
    plotHistograms(m5,m6,m7,d5,d6,d7)
```

### Followup

The next problem you mention is the `&` operator complaining about date data.  That's probably in `filterData`.  The expression `df['weekday'].isin(["5", "6", "7"])` produces an array of booleans.  When you pass that to `df[...]`, that selects a series of rows.  So, `filterWeekday` contains a series of rows, not row selectors.  Thus, your `df.loc` call seems wrong.

I THINK you want this, but without seeing the data, we can't be sure:

```
def filterData(df):
    filterWeekday = df['weekday'].isin(["5", "6", "7"])
    filterDate = (df['date'] < '2021-03-01') & (df['date'] > '2022-03-01')
    return df[filterWeekday & filterDate]
```

In this case, both of the variables are boolean row selection arrays, which CAN be combined with `&`.

And again, I suspect you really want `.isin([5,6,7])` here, assuming that pandas read that column as integers, not strings.

Comment: I did this and it still shows me an error. This is the error that I get:                       
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'DatetimeArray' and 'DatetimeArray'

Comment: But you don't tell us what line that happens in, and we can't provide a definitive answer without seeing the data.  My GUESS is that the problem is in `filterData`, because you are mixing up data rows with boolean indexes.  I'll make a suggestion above.